# Should I create a consumable or a non-renewable subscription for a premium account?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I have an iOS application (and a website). There should be a premium user option i.e the user has access to special content if he/she is a premium user. Users can become premium users on a monthly or yearly basis.

First question - Does Apple allow having the facility to offer the same products for purchase on the website as well as through InAppPurchase (following the rules by Apple - there won't be any link or indication in the app that the same can be bought on the website).
So if a user buys the premium account via InAppPurchase he/she can login to the website as well as a premium user and vice versa.

If that is allowed, is it better to have implemented the premium user functionality using a consumable type product and have the server manage everything or use a non-renewable subscription?

Consumable Approach
Do the InAppPurchase and then send a request to server saying that the current user is a premium user for a month/year and then every time the app launches/user signs in, call an API to check whether the current user is a premium user or not.

The tricky cases to handle are 
1. When the user is using the app exactly when his/her premium user status expires.
2. If network goes off just after the InAppPurchase is done and the request to the server is incomplete.

Non-renewable subscription approach
I'm not sure how this works exactly, but i'm guessing it would be similar to the consumable one.

Which of the two approaches would be better for restoring previous transactions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yep as long as you provide the premium feature in the app (in our Facebook app linked to the iOS one, we implemented Facebook credits for the same features for example)
2. Our app (which was using a consumable in-app to enable a premium feature) have been rejected a couple of times until we switched to a non-renewable subscription.
   The premium feature had a time limit and the reason Apple rejected it was that if the premium feature involves time other than added features you *have to* use a non-renewable subscription since that is its purpose

Tricky cases are not that tricky actually. For the first one, have the app retrieve the expiration time from the server (you did save it after purchasing subscription right? ;-) ) and when the user tries to use a premium feature implement a check to ensure he is still allowed. For the second, save the purchase in the phone and then send the receipt to the server for validation. Only when the server is reachable and says the receipt is valid, delete it from the phone. Otherwise, you can check at start up if there are unsent receipts saved in the phone that you should resend to the server for validation.

Comment: Thanks a lot Andre! One more thing, so to track the duration of the premium user, should we track via an API call to the server or should we check in the app itself using the transaction time. How should we handle multiple accounts as well, i.e if the user does the InAppPurchase and then logs in with a different account?

Comment: I suggest you track the duration with an API call to your server. For multiple accounts, non-renewable subscriptions are tied to the user who bought it and your server is aware of that. So if the apple id who just bought premium, logs out and logs back in with another account, premium features should be disabled imho.

Comment: The Apple ID is the same, but the user logs out and logs into a different account in the app. How do we handle that?

Comment: Sorry i wasn't clear in my previous comment. The Apple ID is the same but if the users in your app are different and only the first bought the premium feature, the second should not have it enabled automatically (in my opinion of course). The second user can of course buy premium again (with the same Apple ID account or not).

Comment: Just one last question - If the user does the InAppPurchase using one account and logs out and logs in with a different account in the app (same Apple ID), it will show a message saying "You have already purchased this product, would you like to buy it again or renew it?". Is there any way to not show that message for a different user?

Comment: The message is appearing when the new user tries to buy the premium feature again or just after logging in? The first case is quite normal since Apple knows his id already bought your premium once. If it is the second case, then there must be something wrong in your implementation.

Comment: The message appears in the first case. But is there any way to not show this message for a new user in the app?

Comment: I don't think you can avoid it (but i am not sure honestly). After all your 'new' user is not really new since he has already bought your premium once at least ;-)

Comment: In my case, I wish to deliver complete feature to the user for free for a limited period say 1 month. After one month app will prompt the user to pay us. If he doesn't pay, app will give him only the basic feature and stop advanced features. Is this possible, if we use Non-Renewing Subscription ?